# Iterating through a nested lst with strings and sublist

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists

Question: **Iterate through the list so that if the character ‘m’ is in the string, then it should be added to a new list called m_list. Hint: Because this isn’t just a list of lists, think about what type of object you want your data to be stored in. Conditionals may help you.**

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've tried storing each sublst in a variable, and looping with a `For`, but is not pythonic.

I've come across wit this solution:

```
def find_char(char, words):
    m_list = []
    for word in words:
        
        if isinstance(word,list):
            m_list += find_char(char,word)
        else:
            if char in word:
                m_list.append(word)
    return  m_list
find_char('m', d)
```

**Which the programm doesn`t accept as is a f.** So, I cannot score the result.

I've come across with this idea:

```
m_list = []
for item in d:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        if 'm' in item:
            m_list.append(item)
        continue
    for inner in item:
        for sub_inner in inner:
            if 'm' in sub_inner:
                m_list.append(sub_inner)
```

**Why, the second for loop `for inner in item` doesn`t loop through both sublist's ?**

*I've tried everything, using `map`, `filter`, storing each sublist in a var so I can use a for loop directly ( bear in mind, it works but is not pythonic and  I want to learn proper code. I can't think of anything else.*

Comment: It's not clear (to me) how your input looks like. Maybe adding an MRE would be a good idea (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Comment: Try running through this with a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to see what's going on.

Comment: @I'm going to pass this one an send them a ticket. Because the programm if the Items are not in the same order they dont score it